# Transforming distribution to exponential with the help of log transformation

Tags: probability

Supose I have distribution function:

$$f_\theta (x) = \theta x^{\theta-1}$$

Then applying this $$Y_i = -\log X_i,$$ we get $$Y_i \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\theta)$$

But I don't see how this transformation works. Can you explain me?

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Evaluate $$\Pr(Y_i \leq y) = \Pr(-\log X_i \leq y) $$

and then compare with CDF of exponential distribution.